# How can I know which user made which USDT transaction?

Tags: api, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am making an app, and I want my users to deposit USDT coin to my address which is an exchange address (I don't have the private keys).

How can I know which user made which transaction?

I have a way, which is to add the numeric user ID to the amount , for example if an user wants to deposit 100.00 USDT coin , and the ID is 158769, I can add the ID in the amount like this: 100.0000158769 and make it as a QR-code so the user should deposit the exact amount so I can know that he made this transaction, but is there any other way to do it , any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Is that exchange address used for other purposes other than transactions for your app? 
As each and every transactions has a sender and a receiver address associate with it and addresses are unique. If your users are registered users for your app or service, in your app you need to maintain your own user database that stores other users information such as email, name, id etc along with user's address to match against. You can query blockchain to get details transaction information against an address. However, other than the transaction information and address real users are always anonymous.

Answer (score -1):

Generate address for each user ID,and combine address,amount to generate the QR code.
It will help you in future if you combine with any other third party API's for the crypto wallet services.Because everyone have address as there user identity ID.